# Dockerized nginx failing in ssl mode

Tags: linux, docker, nginx

I am using `nginx` on `docker`: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx

My `Dockerfile`, in `images/nginx` directory:

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY self-signed.crt /etc/ssl/private
COPY self-signed.key /etc/ssl/private
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  nginx:
    build: images/nginx
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 9080:80
```

This is my config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    # listen 80;  <---- This works!

    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/self-signed.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/self-signed.key;

    location /api/ {
        set                $gateway             api:1234;
        include            uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass         $gateway;

        proxy_set_header   Host                 $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
    }

}
```

This is my `nginx`:

```
root@68f9026bb4fd:/# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.19.4
built by gcc 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/data/builder/debuild/nginx-1.19.4/debian/debuild-base/nginx-1.19.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie'
```

When using the `http` version, with `listen 80` active, it works:

```
» http --headers http://localhost:9080/api/status
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 26 Nov 2020 10:55:11 GMT
Server: nginx/1.19.4
```

The `ngnix` container has the log entry too:

```
nginx_1     | 172.24.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2020:10:55:11 +0000] "GET /api/status HTTP/1.1" 200 21 "-" "HTTPie/2.2.0" "-"
```

But if I now enable the `listen 443 ssl` directive, and disable the `listen 80`, nothing works anymore:

```
» http --headers --verify no https://localhost:9080/api/status

http: error: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')) while doing a GET request to URL: https://localhost:9080/api/status
```

And the `nginx` container has absolutely no log entry. Nothing. Nada!

My cert / key are there, with the right permissions (I think):

```
root@805e850405b1:/# ls -lrt /etc/ssl/private/
total 8
-rw------- 1 root root 3272 Nov 26 10:07 self-signed.key
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1870 Nov 26 10:07 self-signed.crt
```

What is going on here? Is `nginx` receiving requests? If not, Why not?
If yes, why I do not see any log entry? Why is it not replying correctly?

Answer (score 0):

So, obviously the mapping of the port in the docker compose is wrong for `ssl`.

It should be:

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  nginx:
    build: images/nginx
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 9080:80
      - 9443:443
```